# error Object reference not set to an instance of an object when check Facebook Like?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I had error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

at:

```
string[] sB64String = payload.Split('.');
```

When check if user like the my Facebook page, my code-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pageLike();
}

public bool ValidateSignedRequest()
{
    string facebooksecret =
    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FacebookSecret"];
    var VALID_SIGNED_REQUEST = Request.Form["signed_request"];

    string applicationSecret = facebooksecret;
    string[] signedRequest = VALID_SIGNED_REQUEST.Split('.');
    string expectedSignature = signedRequest[0];
    string payload = signedRequest[1];

    // Attempt to get same hash
    var Hmac = SignWithHmac(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload), UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(applicationSecret));
    var HmacBase64 = ToUrlBase64String(Hmac);

    return (HmacBase64 == expectedSignature);
}

private string ToUrlBase64String(byte[] Input)
{
    return Convert.ToBase64String(Input).Replace("=", String.Empty)
                                        .Replace('+', '-')
                                        .Replace('/', '_');
}

private byte[] SignWithHmac(byte[] dataToSign, byte[] keyBody)
{
    using (var hmacAlgorithm = new HMACSHA256(keyBody))
    {
        hmacAlgorithm.ComputeHash(dataToSign);
        return hmacAlgorithm.Hash;
    }
}
public Dictionary<string, string> DecodePayload(string payload)
{
    //Remove the bad part of signed_request
    //Begin
    string[] sB64String = payload.Split('.');
    payload = payload.Replace((sB64String[0] + "."), string.Empty);
    //End
    var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    var decodedJson = payload.Replace("=", string.Empty).Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/');
    var base64JsonArray = Convert.FromBase64String(decodedJson.PadRight(decodedJson.Length + (4 - decodedJson.Length % 4) % 4, '='));
    var json = encoding.GetString(base64JsonArray);
    var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
    var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    parameters.Add("page", ((bool)jObject["page"]["liked"]).ToString());
    parameters.Add("admin", ((bool)jObject["page"]["admin"]).ToString());
    return parameters;
}
protected void pageLike()
{
    string pageLiked = string.Empty;
    var signed_request = Request.Form["signed_request"];
    var json = DecodePayload(signed_request);


    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> objKVP in json)
    {
        //Note You can also see if a user is an admin by replacing the objKVP.Key with admin
        if (objKVP.Key == "page" && objKVP.Value == "True")
        {
            Response.Redirect("https://facebookapp.elarabygroup.com/instruction.aspx");
            //litJson.Text += objKVP.Key + " - " + objKVP.Value + "<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if Payload is in fact null or empty?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything fundamentally wrong with your code, what I suspect is happening is the request form variable is null i.e.

```
var signed_request = Request.Form["signed_request"];
```

the payload variable is being set to a null or empty string. I'd check this and make sure the value is what you expect.

A good idea here is to add a guard clause in DecodePayload to make sure the payload variable has a value before calling the Split method.

e.g.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(payload))
    throw new ArgumentNullException();
```

Comment: @nemoz You're going to need to check what the value of Request.Form["signed_request"] is. From the code above I can't tell where the value is coming from. First port of call would be to search the page that's submitting the request for a control with an ID of 'signed_request' and make sure it's being populated before submitting the form. If it's not spelt correctly or you don't find it, that's probably your problem...